# Banach Space Closed Subspace

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing, banach-spaces

Let $ \mathcal B$ be a Banach Space. Fix $z \in \mathcal B$ with $z \neq 0$. Consider the set

$$A :=\{y-z : y \notin \operatorname{span} \{z\}, y \in \mathcal B\}.$$

Is it true that $\alpha z \notin \overline{A}$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$?

I'm looking for a counterexample or a *hint* about how to prove it, but just  a **hint**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give you a hint. How small can $y$ be? And is $y-z$ ever in the span of $z$?

Comment: Indeed. This is enough information to answer the question rather straightforwardly.

Comment: I don't believe $y-z$ can be in the span if $y$ isn't. But I'm a bit concerned about the closure

Comment: Multiply $y-z$ by $-\alpha$ when $\|y\|<\frac{\epsilon}{\alpha}$